# Hide domain name in Get capabilities request

Tags: geoserver

I am setting up proxy http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities which redirects to geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities. But in Response I can see below
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetTile">
ows:DCP
ows:HTTP
<ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">

I understood it will not show proxy url, but is there any provision to hide the domain atleast localhost:8080 so in short I dont want to show actual domain of my geoserver

or rather show my proxy url i.e xlink:href="http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?">